# Does Android application development Guideline allow disabling Default Menu and back button for particular application?

Tags: android, android-layout, sdk, android-ndk, android-2.2-froyo

In my application there are some buttons that are very near to that device default back button and Menu Button.
Thus I got problem while pressing that My application button which are near to Menu and Back button.

So for that application purpose I want to disable the default back and Menu Button.

So does Android Application development Guideline allow if we want to disable the back and Menu Button during particular application?
If yes then how is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes override onbuttondown... search next time. But its not recommended behaviour.

Comment: @Warpzit : So should i have to implement that for my application or not ? it is a good idea ?

Comment: Overriding default behavior is almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So is Android Application development Guideline allow if we want to disable the back and Menu Button during perticular application?

The guideline of programming for any OS (Windows, Mac, iOS, Android etc.) is **don't break the default behaviour**.

A user will expect that your App supports the default behaviour of the device he/she is using and in most cases bought the device for that very reason: He/she enjoys the default behaviour. If he/she wanted another type of user interaction, he/she would have bought another type of device.

> In my application there are some buttons that are very near to that device default back button and Menu Button

As long as your button is on the screen, I don't see how it can become a problem. If however it in someway is a problem, a better solution than overriding default behaviour is to **move** or **enlarge** your buttons to make it easier for the user to hit them.

> If yes then how it is possible?

Yes, it can be done.

To disable the back button, simply override `onBackPressed()` in whatever `Activity` the problem occurs and leave the implementaion of it empty:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
   //Do nothing
}
```

The Menu Button will only be a problem ifyou inflate a menu from your `Activity`. Standard behaviour is that nothing happens when you hit the Menu Button as long as you don't tell your `Activity` to do something.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try to move the button or make it larger to take effect. Thanks a Lot for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you'll want to override the default behaviour, fx if you use views and the user expects onback to navigate between views. Other times something else, it all depends on the application. I'd recommend to consider if you should override default behaviour or not.

Heres another example that can be used for all the buttons:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && (isSomething)) {
        something();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```