# Android NDK: How to override onBackPressed in NativeActivity without java?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-code

My app is written entirely in C/C++ using `NativeActivity`, it has no Java code (based on "native-activity" NDK example). Pressing "back" button closes it (destroys activity), but I need other behaivor of this button because I have my own UI and menus which are displayed via OpenGL.

[As I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501732/does-android-application-development-guideline-allow-disabling-default-menu-and), In order to change behaivor of "back" button, I need to override `onBackPressed()` method of Java activity class. But I don't use Java, can I reach this method from C/C++ to override it?

If no, is there another way to handle with "back" button using NDK, **without java code?**

Comment: NativeActivity is an Java class!! and you said you are using it!!, so you can override onBackPressed within it?

Comment: No, I mean I'm using it like in "native-activity" NDK example: android_native_app_glue.h, `struct android_app` etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solved: to prevent default "Back" button behaivor it is enough to return 1 while handling key event:

```
int32_t app_handle_event(struct android_app* app, AInputEvent* event) {
    if (AKeyEvent_getKeyCode(event) == AKEYCODE_BACK) {
        // actions on back key
        return 1; // <-- prevent default handler
    };
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```