# Cannot restore the state of my android c++ game (state->savedState is always NULL)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm working on my android full c++ game with android studio and I used this code from google samples (native-activity). Everything works. But when I click on the BACK BUTTON on the emulator, the game goes in background and when I resume the game is restarted from the begining instead of to continue. I add my vars in the state of the app and I'm try reload my "game state" when the app is launched.

The probleme is state->savedState is always equals to NULL. Even after to resume the app.

This is the code : 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/native-activity/app/src/main/cpp/main.cpp#L327

I added this line in my xml : android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" on my activity

Answer (score 1):

You will get a valid **savedState** if your game is preempted by the system. For example, try to make a phone call to the phone that runs the app.

When the user clicks **back** button, the system does not interfere. It is your responsibility to save and restore the game state. You can [intercept  AKEYCODE_BACK in app_handle_event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135531/192373).